# WPF: Give to an UserControl a list of sub controls

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls

I would like to do(for test and education purpose) a wizard.

At the end, I would like to be able to define it like this:

```
<Window ...>
    <Wizard>
        <WizardStep>
        ...
        </WizardStep>
        <WizardStep>
        ...
        </WizardStep>
        <WizardStep>
        ...
        </WizardStep>
    </wizard>
</Window>
```

I don't need skinning or such things, so `UserControl` is fine for me.

Currently I'm struggling on the `Wizard` class, how can I make it allowing a list of subcontrols, and how can I use them inside of my `UserControl`

Answer (score 0):

In the implementation of `Wizard`, use the [`ContentPropertyAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.contentpropertyattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to specify which property the collection of `WizardStep` should be stored in.

**From MSDN:**

> **ContentPropertyAttribute Class**
>
> Indicates which property of a type is the XAML content property. A
>   XAML processor uses this information when processing XAML child
>   elements of XAML representations of the attributed type.

```
[ContentProperty("Title")]
public class Film
{
    public Film()
    {
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set { _title = value; }
    }

    private string _title;
}
```

**Note**

> In order to accept more than a single object element as content, the
>   type of the XAML content property must be supportable as a collection
>   type.

Comment: Oh :) Nice ! I was searching for different parent class or something to override, didn't tough to check for attributes.  I will try it right now, thank you :)

Comment: Just a question, in my case, this will be an `ObservableCollection`, who is responsible for its creation, is it automatically done?

Comment: @J4N I cant say with confidence - try it and see! I would always initialise it in the constructor. There is no guarantee that you will only use it through xaml. If you ask me, classes that force the consumer to initialise their members are very rude!

Comment: Agreed, it's just that I was happy if the framework was doing it ;)